# I can't read the response body in middleware using .NET7

Tags: c#, .net, middleware, .net-7.0

I need to read the response body in a middleware.

I can not read it because the stream is always not readable.

Any advise or solution?

I'm using the next code:

```
  public static IApplicationBuilder UseSendApplicationErrors(this IApplicationBuilder app)  {
  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
      await next(context);
      
      try
      {
          if (context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)
          {
              log = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
              IErrorService errorNotificator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IErrorService>();

              ErrorDto errorRegistry = new ErrorDto()
              {
                  Endpoint = context.Request.Path.Value ?? String.Empty,
                  Method = context.Request.Method,
                  QueryParams = context.Request.QueryString.Value ?? String.Empty,
                  User = context.User.Identity?.Name ?? String.Empty,
              };

              if (context.Response.Body.CanRead)
                  errorRegistry.Message = new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEnd();

              await errorNotificator.SaveErrorAsync(errorRegistry);
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          log?.LogError(e, e.Message);
      }
  });

  return app; }
```

The status of Body is always this:

[image]

The middleware is placed to begin of pipe:

[image]